# Verificar se é o fragment correto após o click (UI Test)

Tags: android, testes, junit

Gostaria de uma dica de como verificar se é o fragment correto após o click

Segue o pensamento (Errado) para exemplificação, alguém tem um exemplo de como posso testar isso?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MapsActivityTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_routes_title));

    @Test
    @SmallTest
    public void showUIMap() {

        onView(withId(R.id.request_textview)).perform(click()).check(assertThat(fragment.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("MyRides)"),is(true));

    }
}
```

Outra dúvida, devo estender o AppCompactivity?

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa fazer o seguinte:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (fm != null) {
                List<Fragment> fragments = fm.getFragments();

                if(fragments != null){
                    for(int i = fragments.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                        final Fragment fragment = fragments.get(i);
                        if(fragment != null) { 
                            if(fragment instanceof NomeDoSeuFragment) {
                                // caso o fragment seja esse faça algo aqui dentro

                            }else if (fragment instanceof NomeDoSeuFragment2){
                                // caso o fragment seja esse faça algo aqui dentro
                            }                       
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Esse looping vai varrer todos os seus fragments, e compara-los com os nomes dos Fragments.

Comment: Opa, obrigado!
Mas não é bem este o raciocinio. Eu quero saber, se ao clicar, será o fragment correto. Estou automatizando testes de interface.